# Simplest Forms of a function

Tags: functions

If $f(x)=2x-3$ and $g(x)=x^2 + 2$
how do i find the simplest forms of:
$f(g(x))$ and $g(f(x))$

Is it just a matter of substituting the equation in or?

Comment: Yes, substitute and simplify if possible

Answer (score 3):

$f(g(x))=2*(x^2+2)-3=2x^2+1$
$g(f(x))=(2x-3)^2+2=4x^2-12x+11$

Comment: Thankyou Andrew, seems to look right

Answer (score 2):

we have $f(g(x))=2(x^2+2)-3=2x^2+1$ and $g(f(x))=(2x-3)^2+2=4x^2-12x+11$